# Why gunicorn parse WSGI directly?

Tags: nginx, wsgi, gunicorn

When we use gunicorn behind nginx, we always need to proxy_pass the request to gunicorn.
But Nginx has a wsgi module which allow it to send wsgi request(uwsgi_pass) to a wsgi application server, and seem like gunicorn can't accept wsgi request directly, it just accept HTTP request and translate it to wsgi and call wsgi application.

Does gunicorn support to accept a wsgi request directly?

if not what can I do if Nginx has some wsgi env parameters which need to send to the wsgi application server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as the 'wsgi' protocol.

The WSGI specification defines a programatic API for Python, not a socket protocol.

You are getting confused with what is a socket protocol called 'uwsgi'. This is entirely different to the HTTP protocol that gunicorn accepts.

The only thing you can use behind nginx which understands the 'uwsgi' protocol is the uWSGI package.

Your choices are to use normal HTTP proxying and gunicorn, or uwsgi proxying and uWSGI.

Comment: So for WSGI, it's still based on HTTP protocol right?

Comment: What can I do if I want to pass some self-defined parameters to gunicorn?

Comment: No, WSGI API interface is not strictly bound to HTTP. The uWSGI package bridges between the uwsgi protocol and the WSGI API interface. If you want to pass process wide parameters into your WSGI application running under gunicorn, then use environment variables. What are the parameters for?

Comment: That's a connectionID which belongs to a internal some kind of "server" with a private protocol, I have a Nginx module to make a connection to that "server", so I have to deliver it to wsgi application, because it need to interact with that server using that connectionID.

Comment: Look at whether nginx allows you to pass the connection ID via a special X-Connection-ID HTTP header. Whether proxying via HTTP or uwsgi protocol, if you can set the header some how when request proxied, the backend should be able to see it.

Comment: Yes, I think so, Thanks Graham!